# Install "context" package in golang?

Tags: go

I'm trying to install the `context` package in golang, which I did like this :

```
go get golang.org/x/net/context
```

But when I do an `import "context"`, I still get the following error :

```
cannot find package "context" in any of:
/usr/lib/go-1.6/src/context (from $GOROOT)
/home/saurabh/work/src/context (from $GOPATH)
```

Can anyone suggest how to install this package ? I'm currently using version `go1.6.2`.

Comment: Follow the link: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/issues/711.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

change `import "context"` to `import "golang.org/x/net/context"`.

but after go 1.7 you can use `import "context"`, as it had become a standard library.

> Go 1.7 moves the golang.org/x/net/context package into the standard library as context.

see 1.7 release notes: https://golang.org/doc/go1.7#context

Comment: I did it, but it still doesn't work. I get an error in declaring an object like this : `r.Context undefined (type *http.Request has no field or method Context)`, where `r` is a pointer to an object of type `http.Request`.

Comment: @Jarvis I believe  `http.Request.Context` is available only since 1.7. If you want to use `r.Context` you need to upgrade from 1.6.2 to 1.7+, then you'll also be able to use `import "context"`. Here are the 1.7 [net/http release notes](https://golang.org/doc/go1.7#net_http).

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue , below are the steps to fix:

1. Download the latest version  https://golang.org/doc/install?download=go1.9.2.linux-arm64.tar.gz
2. Extract the tar to /usr/local/ .

Use Command ->
**tar -xzvf go1.9.2.linux-arm64.tar.gz -C /usr/local**

3. Replace the symlink pointing to go:

**sudo rm /usr/bin/go

sudo ln -s /usr/local/go/bin/go /usr/bin/go**

*Reference: https://github.com/DieterReuter/arm64-docker-builder/issues/7*